How to handle certificate error and connection termination error while accessing RDP with Pywinauto
I am trying to open an RDP session using Pywinauto. I can run the RPA until I enter the password and click "OK" to log in. However, in this RDP session, once logged in, a dialog box shows a certificate error, and I have to click "Yes" to proceed. Upon clicking the "Yes" button, the RDP session will open, or sometimes it will show "connection termination". If I receive this error, I must click the "OK" button and start again to open it successfully.
I am using UIA Verify to check the elements. Here's the screenshot of the Certificate error.

And below is the screenshot of the Remote Connection Terminated.

See below method;
def handle_dialog():
    try:
        dialogs = Desktop(backend='uia').windows(title="Remote Desktop Connection", visible_only=False)
    
    for dialog in dialogs:
        conn_termination_dialog = None
        cert_dialog = None
        
        button_controls = dialog.children(control_type="Button")
        for button in button_controls:
            if button.element_info.name == "OK":
                conn_termination_dialog = button
            elif button.element_info.name == "Yes":
                cert_dialog = button
        
        if cert_dialog and cert_dialog.is_visible():
            cert_dialog.click_input()  
            return True  
        elif conn_termination_dialog and conn_termination_dialog.is_visible():
            conn_termination_dialog.click_input()
            return True
    
        print("Dialog not found or not visible.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling dialog: {str(e)}")
    return False

I have tried a different approach but still, it can't detect the buttons. It will just print "Dialog not found or not visible."

Well, why not use the pywin32 library to help? win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) could both be useful here.  You can use pyautogui to click onthe window and tab through the buttons, then press enter to select.

Will try the pywin32. Using pyautogui is out of my options because it is not reliable.

I'm not sure why you need RDP window automation. Because you cannot see UI elements inside RDP session anyway (by design). If you need to run your script remotely, you need to copy it to remote machine and run there. And you need to follow one of these recipes: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html

Because the application I need to access can be accessed only through RDP. So I need to handle the RDP login first.

If you read the recipes carefully, you can find the way to still use RDP and still copy pywinauto-based script and run it remotely. So the app will run in RDP window, but the script will also run inside the same RDP window (i.e. remotely).
